# Linear Second order differential equation, special method?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation is as follows:
$(x+1)y''-(2x+3)y'+(x+2)y=0$ where $y(x)$ is a funtion on $\mathbb{R}$. First, I had to show that $y_1(x)=e^x$ is a solution for the DV. The second question was to find the general solution of the DV. I instantly started on the series of solution solving method, but I think I have to use the 'hint'  $y_1(x)=e^x$ is a solution to the DV, but how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$y(x) = y_1(x) \, z(x) = e^x \, z(x),$$
where $z(x)$ is your new unknown function. Then $y'(x) = e^x \, z(x) + e^x \, z'(x)$ and $y''(x) = \cdots$, and when you substitute this into your ODE you get something with a $z''$ term and a $z'$ term, but no $z$ term, so if you let $w(x)=z'(x)$ you get a first-order linear ODE for $w$, and such equations can always be solved in principle, using an integrating factor.

(This procedure is called *reduction of order*.)

Comment: Thank you. +1 I genuinely have no idea why I didn't use this exact method when I obviously used it two days ago for my own problem

Answer (score 1):

It's a linear homogeneous equation, you can lower the order of equation by the following, **general** method:

$$y(x)=e^{s(x)}$$

$$y'=s'e^{s}$$

$$y''=s''e^{s}+s'^2e^{s}$$

Substituting this and dividing by $e^s$, you have:

$$(x+1)s''+(x+1)s'^2-(2x+3)s'+(x+2)=0$$

Now set:

$$s'(x)=p(x)$$

You obtain a first order **nonlinear** ode:

$$(x+1)p'+(x+1)p^2-(2x+3)p+(x+2)=0 \tag{*}$$

It's a Riccati equation.

The nice thing about Riccati equation is that if you know any particular solution, there's a way to express the general solution through it.

I'll expand more on this below:

---

Let $p_0$ be a particular solution to (*). In the OP case it's:

$$p_0=1$$

Now let the general solution be still denoted as $p$. Substitute the sum of these two solutions in (*):

$$(x+1)(p_0'+p')+(x+1)(p_0^2+2p_0p+p^2)-(2x+3)(p_0+p)+(x+2)=0$$

Note that because (*) is nonlinear the sum of two solutions is not a solution to the original equation anymore. However, since each of them separately is still a solution, we can substitute $p_0$ and see:

$$p_0=1$$

$$(x+1)p'+(x+1)(1+2p+p^2)-(2x+3)(1+p)+(x+2)=0$$

Or, simplifying:

$$(x+1)p'+(x+1)p^2-p=0 \tag{**}$$

The equation (**) is a [Bernoulli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) and can be solved by the following method:

$$q(x)=\frac{1}{p(x)}$$

$$-(x+1)\frac{q'}{q^2}+(x+1)\frac{1}{q^2}-\frac{1}{q}=0 $$

$$q'-1+\frac{q}{(1+x)}=0 \tag{3}$$

Now (3) is finally a linear first odrer ODE as promised. Going back through all the substitutions will bring the general solution of the original equation

Comment: Thanks, and yes I do

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising, you are welcome

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising, wait, I made a mistake: the second equation is wrong

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising, please see the corrected answer. I apologise for leading you astray, but consider this a lesson: don't trust the first person on the internet

Comment: This seems terribly complicated... Why don't you just use the ordinary reduction of order procedure $y(x) = y_1(x) \, z(x) = e^x \, z(x)$ to get a *linear* first order ODE for $z'(x)$?

Comment: @HansLundmark, because I didn't remember this process, and I needed to fix my wrong accepted answer fast. Please  post the correct answer and let's hope the op comes back and accepts it. I will not be answering questions hastily in the future to avoid such mistakes

Comment: And I can't even delete an accepted answer which is terribly inconvenient

Comment: @YuriyS sorry for marking the problem as solved. The reason I did is because you mentioned  a method of substitution and I instantly knew what to do, and didn't read the full answer.

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising, it's alright, as long as you solved your problem correctly